# how to create random number in nasm getting system time?

Tags: random, printing, nasm

I need to create teen random numbers using system time like seed to create the numbers, it need to be done in nasm with linux kernel.
and i can't use gcc whith C code. only with ld.

so how can i create at least one number and print it?

Comment: Why can't you use the C Libs?  Experts in pseudorandom number generators, and number theory, have created and tested the random functions.  You can use `RDTSC` but that won't be truly random.

Answer (score 0):

The assembler instruction `RDTSC` returns the Time Stamp Counter in `EDX:EAX`. It counts the number of CPU cycles since reset.

```
RDTSC
AND EAX, FFH
```

this supposed to give you a random number between 0 and 255